# json decode error expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to get an mpesa authentication token which is json format. It gives an error in the decoding code

Below is my views.py

```
import requests
import json
def getAccessToken(request):
    consumer_key = ''
    consumer_secret = ''
    api_URL = 'https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate? 
    grant_type=client_credentials'

    r = requests.get(api_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret))
    mpesa_access_token = json.loads(r.text)
    validated_mpesa_access_token = mpesa_access_token['access_token']

    return HttpResponse(validated_mpesa_access_token)
```

Below is my projects urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('store.urls')),
]
```

where store is the name of my app

My store urls.py,

```
from django.urls import path

from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('access/token/', views.getAccessToken, name='get_mpesa_access_token'),
]
```

When I access that url instead of giving me the token I want, it gives the error below:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 24, 2021 - 20:45:26
Django version 2.2, using settings 'mvee.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /access/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/Desktop/projects/django2.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/Desktop/projects/django2.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/Desktop/projects/django2.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/Desktop/projects/venv/MVEE/src/store/views.py", line 121, in getAccessToken
    mpesa_access_token = json.loads(r.text)
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/victor_nzioka/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[24/Aug/2021 20:45:31] "GET /access/token/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87044
```

I tried doing this but it did not work.

```
r = requests.get(api_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret)).json()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  What you're getting back is not JSON.  Did you `print(r.text)` to see exactly what you're getting back?

Comment: In your own words, when you call `requests.get(api_URL, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret))`, what exactly do you expect to get back, and why? Did you test that expectation?

Comment: @TimRoberts in fact when I try printing the r.text it does not print anything. It just gives a success status code of 200 and that's all.

Comment: Can we assume your URL is actually all typed on one line, and not split like it is above?

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah it is a one line

Comment: in fact when I tried print(r.text) and did not see anything I guessed there was a problem with the url. After creating a new app to be accessed by the url everything is okay now. The code is perfectly working now.